# DatabaseConnections has no JNDI context so cannot list connections

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Just opened the Oracle SQL Developer and i'm getting this error:

> Failed to create naming Context for db connections at url: file:/C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/SQL Developer/system3.2.20.09.87/o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48/connections.xml
>
> SEVERE    95  69513   oracle.jdevimpl.db.adapter.DefaultContextWrapper    Failed to create naming Context for db connections at url: file:/C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/SQL Developer/system3.2.20.09.87/o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.4.37.59.48/connections.xml
>
> SEVERE    96  0   oracle.jdeveloper.db.DatabaseConnections    DatabaseConnections has no JNDI context so cannot list connections.

and I've lost all my connections... the connections.xml seems empty

any idea on how to fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Here is what worked for me.

connections.xml file just contained repetitive string NULL

I simply deleted this file and created a new connection which went through fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

- STEP 1: Deleting the file `connections.xml` under the path: `C:\Users\tejgm\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system2.1.1.64.45\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.2.36.55.30`.
- STEP 2: Start up the SQL newly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be a necromancer, but I found this happens when the C: drive (where Users\xxx\AppData is located) becomes full. For some reason, when adding connections to the connetions.xml file, the app does not just append/write to the file, it completely overwrites the file. If there is no space on the target drive, nothing gets written.

Comment: You are correct it does a full write the the entire file so the full filesystem will cause that to fail. I always have an export of my connections.